# Getting all records from sqlite database by branch and year

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to display only that records where branch is electrical and year is 1 from sqlite database.here i displayed all records it works perfect but i didn't know query for my problem.Thanks in advance

```
 // Getting All Contacts
        public ArrayList<Contact> Get_Contacts() {
        try {
            contact_list.clear();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setBranch(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setYear(cursor.getString(4));
                contact.setDate(cursor.getString(5));
                contact.setStatus(cursor.getString(6));
              //  contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                contact_list.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return contact list
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return contact_list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
        }

        return contact_list;
        }
```

Comment: write an if condition if(branch is eletrical && year is 1) add it to array list and show in a Listview

Comment: I have edited my answer.. check it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<Contact> Get_Contacts(int year,String branch) {
    try {
        contact_list.clear();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS+" where branch=? and year=?";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,new String[]{branch,year});

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setBranch(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setYear(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setDate(cursor.getString(5));
            contact.setStatus(cursor.getString(6));
          //  contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
            // Adding contact to list
            contact_list.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return contact_list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
    }

    return contact_list;
    }
```

I assume that you store your branch and year information in column 'branch' and 'year' , if its not, replace them with correct column names in "selectQuery" variable

Answer (score 0):

query should be `select * from table where branch='electrical'` something like that. It will solve the issue.